# Selenium script for selecting value from dropdown as per value given by user from console

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have added a image (Stripe.com) i want to select a  specific value from drop down as per user pass from console.Please help me with this.

As Per my code it is taking zero values from drop down to compare with user value.

Here it is

```
 dropdown=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='select2-results-18']//li[@role='presentation']/div/span[@class='card-name']"));
       int a1=dropdown.size();
       System.out.println(a1);
   for(int i=0;i<a1;i++)
   {
       System.out.println("hhh");
      String s1=dropdown.get(i).getText();
      System.out.println(s1);
         if((s1.compareToIgnoreCase(card))==0)
         {
             dropdown.get(i).click();   
           break;

           }
         else
             System.out.println("Fail");
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dropdown element type is to be used here which has inbuilt methods to select dropdown options either by text/value or index.

```
SelectElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='select2-results-18']//li[@role='presentation']/div/span[@class='card-name']"));
dropdown.SelectByText(userInput);
```

Comment: you need to import class with SelectElement. 
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
If that doesn't works, please share the error message.

Comment: I tried with importing a class still it is showing "SelectElement cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: Please use "import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;"

Comment: Are you trying to select options from a single dropdown? You should be using driver.findElement instead of driver.findElements.

Comment: I have imported and trying with findElements but same error

Comment: It won't help to import `support.ui.Select` if the code above doesn't show the correct use of the `Select()` class. `Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")); dropdown.selectByText(userInput);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("XXXXX"));

List<WebElement> list = dropdown.getOptions();
for (WebElement temp : list) { 
    if (temp.getText().equals("your value").toString()) {
    System.out.println("Pass");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Try again");

}
```

Comment: Showing this error " java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement"

Comment: code Like this                                                 Select dropdown1 = new Select((WebElement) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='select2-results-18']//li[@role='presentation']/div/span[@class='card-name']")));

         List<WebElement> list = dropdown1.getOptions();
          for (WebElement temp : list) { 
  if (temp.getText().equals(card)) {
  System.out.println("Pass");
  }
  else{
  System.out.println("Try again");

  }
  }

Comment: Please use "import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select sel=new Select(wd.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='select2-results-18']//li[@role='presentation']/div/span[@class='card-name']")));
    sel.selectByVisibleText(card);
```

Import import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select; for using Select.

Please make sure you are choosing select element xpath.